# Updating view model from object not working

Tags: knockout.js

I want to be able to observe an object inside the view model. I have a simple example that doesn't work as expected, can anyone see the problem?

Using knockout 1.1.1, have 2 inputs as such:

```html
<form data-bind="submit: save">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: deckName" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: deck().Name" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

When the page loads, the inputs get the default values, but on submitting the form `viewModel.deck().Name` is not updated but `viewModel.deckName` is.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = {"Name":"test"};

    var viewModel = {
        deck: ko.observable(initialData),
        deckName: initialData.Name,
        save: function() {
            ko.utils.postJson(location.href, { deck: this.deck, deckName: this.deckName });
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

On the form POST, `deck` will still send "test" no matter the input whilst `deckName` will be the corresponding input value.

What I really want is to be able to observe an object `viewModel.deck` and then bind its properties to inputs, but the properties don't get updated.

Answer (score 7):

There are several problems with what you have provided.

1. You've only set up a one time value setter for your second input since `deck().Name` is a [static value](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) (as opposed to a `ko.observable` or a `ko.observableArray`).  (To prove this add `viewModel.deck({"Name":"updated test"});` to the end of your script after `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);`)
2. `deckName` is a one way binding - it's written during the initial `applyBindings` and `viewModel` will be updated by changes made by the user or scripts to the `<input>`.  However, if you make programmatic changes to the `viewModel` your input field will not be updated to match.  You'll want to take a look at the last part of Knockout.js' [value binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html).

A slightly improved version:

```
<form data-bind="submit: save">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: deckName" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: deck().Name" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = {"Name":"test"};

    var viewModel = {
        deck: ko.observable(initialData),
        // Set up a two way binding
        deckName: ko.observable(initialData.Name),
        // Set up a one time value setter
        save: function() {
            ko.utils.postJson(location.href, ko.toJSON(this));
            // When we save the model we post *it* back, rather than
            // serializing it by hand.
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    viewModel.deck({"Name":"updated test"});
</script>
```

An alternate version using [`fromJS`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins.mapping.html):

```
<form data-bind="submit: save">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = {"Name":"test"};

    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData);
    viewModel.save = function() {
        ko.utils.postJson(location.href, ko.toJSON(this));
        // When we save the model we post *it* back, rather than
        // serializing it by hand.
    }
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

You'll want to look at Knockout's [`fromJSON`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins.mapping.html) and [`fromJS`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins.mapping.html) funcitons (implemented in its [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins.mapping.html)).

Comment: Good point on the one way binding on deckName. What I want is a viewModel with 'deck' as an observable which comes from JSON and then be able to add other properties to the viewModel which don't come from JSON.

Comment: @yanta -- you can add other properties that do not come from the JSON object after you've called `fromJSON`.  The model can be constructed programmatically; it doesn't have to be put together all in one go.

Comment: @Sean Vieira - I took your second example and copied into a page but viewModel is undefined, the Name isn;t diaplyed in the input and the form doesn't post. Any idea?

Comment: @yanta -- did you include the knockout.mapping extension on the page? https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping

Comment: the mapping module is defined in the page like this <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>

Comment: Ah, ko.fromJS should be ko.mapping.fromJS :)