# How to make knockout binding work for dynamically added nested objects?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I wonder how to make knockout binding work for dynamically added nested objects. The following sample demostrates what I mean, it does not show "inner value" as I click 'Init inner' button:

```
<div data-bind="with: InnerObj">
    <div data-bind="text: Pr"></div>
</div>

<button data-bind="click: initInner">Init inner</button>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var obj = { 
   InnerObj: null,
   initInner: function () { 
         this.InnerObj = { Pr: "inner value" };
   }
 }

$(function () {        
    ko.applyBindings(ko.mapping.fromJS(obj));
});    

</script>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on why you would need to do this. You are declaring in the binding that an object `InnerObj` will have a property `Pr`, so you already know at design-time what the structure of the object is. Why not make the object like that, and just update the values?

Comment: obj is supposed to come from web server where it can be null in some cases, however it might be created on a client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare this object as an observable and set its value accessing it as a function

```
<button data-bind="click: initInner">Init inner</button>
<div data-bind="with: InnerObj">
   <span data-bind="text: Pr"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var obj = { 
   InnerObj:  ko.observable(),
   initInner: function () {   
      this.InnerObj({'Pr':ko.observable('Inner value')});
   }
}


$(function () {        
    ko.applyBindings(obj);
});    

</script>
```

key points:1 - InnerObj:  ko.observable()
           2 - this.InnerObj({'Pr':ko.observable('Inner value')});

references:http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html - [Updating view model from object not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493168/updating-view-model-from-object-not-working-in-knockout-js)

Comment: This sample works, thank you. The only thing I do not quite like is an idea to make InnerObj observable on declaration, what if my model is taken from server via Ajax request? Can I setup KO mapping so that it maps null into ko.observable(null)? It would solve the problem

Comment: I've modified your sample a little bit to make it work for my case where obj is taken from web server and not supposed to be modified in javascript code. Thank you, you gave me idea to go!

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly modified example of what @Victor Eloy proposed. In the case `obj`  is a pure model taken from server w/o any observables. The trick is to map it to ko.observable(null) which KO mapping does not do by default unfortunately.

```
<button data-bind="click: initInner">Init inner</button>

<div data-bind="with: InnerObj"> 
    <div data-bind="text: Pr"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var obj = {
    // This case works too: InnerObj: { Pr: "init value"},
    InnerObj: null,

    initInner: function () {
        this.InnerObj({ Pr: ko.observable("new value") });
    }
};

var mapping = {
    'InnerObj': {
        update: function (options) {
            return (options.data == null) ? null : ko.observable(options.data);
        }
    }
};

$(function () {
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(obj, mapping);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```